# Google+ Plus API Define a specific image variable

Tags: php, api

I am trying to integrate the Google+ API on my website so that when a user submits approval via Oauth their Google+ activity feed will be displayed.

I have all of it working pretty much and am working on defining the variables that it will display for their feed.

Currently, this is what I have that IS working:

```
$activityMarkup = '';
foreach($activities['items'] as $activity) { 

$url = filter_var($activity['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
$title = filter_var($activity['title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$content = filter_var($activity['object']['content'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$published = $activity['published'];
$totalItems = $activity['object']['plusoners']['totalItems'];


$activityMarkup .= "<div class='activity'>
        <a href='".$url."' target='_blank'>$title</a>
        <div>$content</div>
        <div><br/><span>Date Published: </span>$published</div>
        <div><br/><span>Total Likes: </span>$totalItems</div>
        </div><br/><br>";
```

What I am trying to get to work is adding in the image that is associated with the post, namely the thumbnail.

I have tried different variations based on using existing code that works, but I just can't figure it out.

According to the Google API, this is the information for that image:

object.attachments[].image  object  The preview image for photos or videos.
object.attachments[].image.url  string  URL of the link.

Here's a link to all of the activities available if the above information isn't enough:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities#object.originalContent

If someone can help me figure out how to define the variable for the image, that'd be awesome.

I figured it out. If anyone needs it, here's the code.

```
$image=''; 
if(isset($activity['object']['attachments'])){ 
foreach($activity['object']['attachments'] as $att){ 
if(isset($att['image']['url'])) { 
$src = $att['image']['url'];
```

To call it out:

```
<img src='$src'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php 
   $image=''; 
    if(isset($activity['object']['attachments']))
    { 
            foreach($activity['object']['attachments'] as $att)
            { 
                if(isset($att['image']['url'])) 
                { 
                $src = $att['image']['url'] ;
                }
            }

    }
    ?>        


   <img src='<?php echo $src ?>'>
```

Works a Treat - https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities#object.originalContent

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($activities['items'] as $activity): ?>
<div class="activity" >
    <div class="title" ><a href="<?php echo($activity['object']['url']) ; ?>" ><?php echo($activity['object']['content']); ?></a></div>
    <p>Published at <?php echo($activity['published']); ?></p>
    <p>
        <?php echo($activity['object']['replies']['totalItems']); ?> Replys . 
        <?php echo($activity['object']['plusoners']['totalItems']); ?> Plusoners . 
        <?php echo($activity['object']['resharers']['totalItems']); ?> Reshares
    </p>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Another Way to add to the Feed is with replies, plusoners and reshares